# Refresh parent page when button clicked in child page

Tags: php, mysql, html, ajax, parent-child

Basically, I have a main page (parent page) with a link that opens up another page (child page) which contains buttons within it. What I want, is when the user clicks the button within the child page, the mysql database will be updated, then I want the parent page to be refreshed (displaying the updated values from the database).

I am currently using PHP for my server side programming. Can anyone suggest the best and simplest way to do this? Should it be done using AJAX? Please point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This
I assume by child window you mean a window that was opened by code in the opener window, and the opener window is the parent window.

If so, you can use the following code in the child window:

```
window.opener.location.reload();
window.close()
```

`window.opener` is a reference to the window that opened the current window.

Answer (score 2):

Just for refresh no need for AJAX. It can be done with simple `javascript`. The page of pop-up window, we just need to put following `javascript` after all your database insert/update operation completed.

```
<script>
        window.opener.location.reload();
</script>
```